# SQL WHERE NOT IN query returning values that are in the other table

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to run 2 `SELECT` queries. The first query selects all data from `Supplier_Product_Pricing` where the chosen customer and supplier match. This fills in a `DataTable`, and shows the Supplier, Product and Price. This one works fine.

The next query I'm trying to execute should be selecting all products from `Product Suppliers` where the supplier matches the chosen supplier, but hasn't been given a price for the chosen customer in `Supplier_Product_Pricing`.

Essentially, I want to load data from 2 tables, one set of records where there is an agreed price between the chosen customer and supplier, which is then joined with a second set of data, which is the remaining products for that supplier, without an agreed price.

The following is the code I'm using to do this:

```
Try
   sql = "SELECT * FROM [Supplier_Product_Pricing] WHERE [Customer_Code] = @ccode AND " & _
         "[Supp_Code] = @scode ORDER BY [Product_Code]"
   cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)

    With cmd.Parameters
       .AddWithValue("@ccode", cust)
        .AddWithValue("@scode", cmbSuppCode.Text)
    End With

   Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
   Dim dt As New DataTable
   da.Fill(dt)

   Dim i As Integer = dt.Rows.Count

    Dim ds As New DataSet
        Using da2 As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Product Suppliers] WHERE " & _
                                         "[Supplier_Code] = ? AND [Product_Code] NOT IN " & _
                                        "(SELECT [Product_Code] FROM " & _
                                        "[Supplier_Product_Pricing] WHERE [Customer_Code] = ? " & _
                                        "AND [Supp_Code] = ?) ORDER BY [Product_Code]", con)
            With da2.SelectCommand.Parameters
                .Add("@scode", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbSuppCode.Text
                .Add("@ccode", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cust
                .Add("@supp", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbSuppCode.Text
            End With

            da2.Fill(ds)
        End Using

  For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
     dt.Rows.Add(dr.Item("Supplier_Code"), dr.Item("Product_Code"), Nothing)
  Next
```

But the result of this, is that it displays all records with a price agreed at the top, and then shows all of that suppliers products again under it, regardless of whether there is a price agreed or not. See below.

[image]

As you can see, the 4 rows with a product price are then repeated below but without a price.

Why is the query returning rows that are in both tables, despite using a `NOT IN` clause?

**EDIT**

To help with the bounty - When using one parameter, as suggested in the first answer, no results are returned at all.

When using 2 different parameters, as I initially did, it returns the same results as shown in the image, whether I use `DISTINCT` or not.

Table [`Product Suppliers`] - Stores all of the products that have been given a supplier. So, in the example given, all of the products associated to 'JON_B' would be in here with 'JON_B' as the supplier. All of JON_B's products are seen in the image below.

[image] [image]

Table [`Supplier_Product_Pricing`]

[image]

As you can see, there are only 8 products linked to JON_B. When adding a price to 4 of them, it then returns the 4 with a price, as well as all  again without a price. I need to only display the ones with a price from `Supplier_Product_Pricing`, plus the ones without a price in `Product Suppliers`

**EDIT 2**

Following on from the answer provided by @Bugs

```
Dim sqlString As String = "   SELECT [Product Suppliers].[Supplier_Code], " & _
                        "          [Product Suppliers].[Product_Code], " & _
                        "          [Supplier_Product_Pricing].[Product_Price] " & _
                        "     FROM [Product Suppliers] LEFT OUTER JOIN " & _
                        "          [Supplier_Product_Pricing] ON [Product Suppliers].[Product_Code]=[Supplier_Product_Pricing].[Product_Code] AND " & _
                        "                                        [Product Suppliers].[Supplier_Code]=[Supplier_Product_Pricing].[Supp_Code] " & _
                        "   WHERE [Product Suppliers].[Supplier_Code] = ? " & _
                        "     AND [Supplier_Product_Pricing].[Customer_Code] = ? " & _
                        "ORDER BY [Product Suppliers].[Product_Code]"

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlString, con)

            With cmd.Parameters
                .Add(New OleDbParameter("@scode", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = cmbSuppCode.Text
                .Add(New OleDbParameter("@ccode", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = cust
            End With

            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())

        ugPricing.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Override.AllowAddNew = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.AllowAddNew.No
        ugPricing.DataSource = dt

        Try
            ugPricing.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns("Customer_Code").Hidden = True
        Catch
        End Try
```

This time it's just showing the items with a price, not the ones without.
[image]

Data from the relevant tables:

[`Product Suppliers`]

[image]

[`Supplier_Product_Pricing`]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are after can be done in one query instead of using two and then adding rows to `dt`. I've popped the query into a variable to try and make it a little easier to read in this answer.

I'm also loading straight into a `DataTable`. This is just my preference.

Replace both queries with this is bit of code:

```
Dim sqlString As String = "   SELECT [Product Suppliers].[Supplier_Code], " & _
                          "          [Product Suppliers].[Product_Code], " & _
                          "          [Supplier_Product_Pricing].[Product_Price] " & _
                          "     FROM [Product Suppliers] LEFT OUTER JOIN " & _
                          "          [Supplier_Product_Pricing] ON ([Product Suppliers].[Product_Code]=[Supplier_Product_Pricing].[Product_Code] AND " & _
                          "                                         [Product Suppliers].[Supplier_Code]=[Supplier_Product_Pricing].[Supp_Code] AND " & _
                          "                                         [Supplier_Product_Pricing].[Customer_Code] = ?) " & _
                          "   WHERE [Product Suppliers].[Supplier_Code] = ? " & _
                          "ORDER BY [Product Suppliers].[Product_Code]"

Dim dt As New DataTable
Using cn As OleDbConnection = con,
      cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlString, cn)

    cn.Open()

    With cmd.Parameters
        .Add(New OleDbParameter("@ccode", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = cust
        .Add(New OleDbParameter("@scode", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = cmbSuppCode.Text
    End With

    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
End Using
```

This is a screenshot of my data:

[image]

Give it a go and see what it does for you.

<sup>I've replicated this on [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) as I don't have [ms-access](/questions/tagged/ms-access) but the same query should work.</sup>

Comment: YES! That's done it, thank you. I'll need to make a couple of tweaks but this does now display what I need it to. Thanks for sticking with this.

Comment: @David, not a problem, glad we could sort it.

Answer (score 0):

There  are two changes in it. I noticed you are using different parameter name for same supplier , i think that is not necessary and I used distinct for product_code from supplier_product_pricing table.

```
Select * from productSuppliers 
 where supplier_code = @sCode  
   and product_code NOT in  
    (select distinct product_code from supplier_product_pricing 
     where customer_code = @cust 
     and supp_code = @sCode) 
  Order by Product_code
```

Comment: First of all, it has to use different parameters for the supplier because it's `MS-Access`. This still makes no difference at all, even with the `DISTINCT` part.